# How can I disable SSL (https) google search in FireFox?

Tags: firefox, ssl, https, google-search

I know that Firefox 14 has enabled Secure Sockets Layer (SSL or https) search for its Google search plug-in. How can I disable it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Go to `%programfiles%\Mozilla Firefox\searchplugins`
2. Open `google.xml`
3. Replace any `https://...` By `http://...`
4. Do not forget to log out your Google account. If you are logged in, you will be redirected to the SSL protocol.

Comment: Brilliant! I was looking for that whole web. :D

Answer (score 0):

It's been a year since breceivemail answered this question and there are little changes:

If you can not find `google.xml` file or by chnaging it, nothing happens, follow these instructions:

- If you have not created a Firefox profile:

  1. Go to `%programfiles%\Mozilla Firefox\browser\searchplugins`
  2. Open `google.xml`  file and replace `https`  with `http`.
  3. Save it and you're done.

     - If you have a firefox profile created, After changing `google.xml`:
  4. Go to your Firefox profile. [HOW?](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Profiles#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile)
  5. Delete `search.json`  file and reopen your Firefox

Comment: non of these two solutions works for me now :(

Comment: @breceivemail what version do you use?

Comment: version 24.0 beta

Comment: @breceivemail It's google not firefox!

Comment: I've searched but it seems there no easy way to stop google from redirecting requests to **HTTPS**.

Comment: You can get Google to knock off the redirects by changing your user agent string.  I put my experience in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

The above accepted answer used to work for me, but it appears it is no longer sufficient. I noticed using Fiddler that sending HTTP requests to Google would always return 302s, redirecting me to the HTTPS url as long as a Firefox user agent string was included in the request header.  This is my current user agent string using Firefox 24 on Windows 7 x64:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0`

So for me, a simple fix was to start using the [User Agent Quick Switch](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/user-agent-quick-switch/) add-on for Firefox.  I changed my user agent string like this - just removed the Firefox/24.0 at the end:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101`

And now I am getting Google without HTTPS again.  Go figure.